# Cannot set ClientCredentials for WCF SOAP Request

Tags: wcf, soap

I am using Visual Studio 2019 to try to create a .Net 4.5.2 client that consumes a remote Web service using SOAP over HTTPS.  To authenticate, the service requires a client certificate be attached to all requests.  The client instantiates the System.ServiceModel.ClientBase class.  It seems no matter how I generate the client class, I cannot set the ClientCredentials I think because the ClientCredentials are read-only.

Here's the commands I used to generate the client class:

```
svcutil.exe /t:metadata https://example.com?WSDL
svcutil.exe /language:cs /config:app.config /messagecontract *.xsd *.wsdl
```

Here's the binding I use in my web.config file:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TCSOnlineServicePortBinding">
      <!-- I am not sure of the mode below, message also does not work -->
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://example.com"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCSOnlineServicePortBinding"
      contract="TCSOnlineService" name="TCSOnlineServicePort" />
</client>
```

Here's the code that doesn't work:

```
  var TCSSvcClient = new TCSOnlineServiceClient(tcs_endpoint, TCSEndpointAddr);
  var aCert = new X509Certificate2();
  ... [omitting code to find cert in MY store]
  // The line below leave the ClientCertificate.Certificate set to NULL????? Why??
  TCSSvcClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = aCert;
  // This also does not work, certificate is left NULL
  TCSSvcClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2();
```

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not a .NET guru, but it is not enough to provide the certificate. For client authentication your code must have access to the private key, too.

Answer (score 0):

We had better configure the certificate by using the `LocalMachine store` and then add the current user running the client application to the management group of the private key of the certificate.

```
ServiceReference1.TestServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.TestServiceClient();
            client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "9ee8be61d875bd6e1108c98b590386d0a489a9ca");
            var result = client.GetResult("a");
            result = client.Test();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

[image]
For the client’s certificate generated with `Powershell`, we had better target the application DotNet4.6.2 or above.
There is a problem to supply a client certificate in this way. We need to ensure that the current user can read the private key of the certificate.

```
  TCSSvcClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2();
```

Besides, authenticating the client with a certificate requires a trust relationship between the client-side and the server-side. have you established the trust relationship before calling the service?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: The link to transport security with certificate authentication seems like what I was looking for.  Thanks!